# Пестовать и пестик

Tags: однокоренные-слова

Что такое пестик, думаю, объяснять не надо. Пестик может быть у цветка, у колокола, может быть пестик, которым растирают что-то в ступке.
Но одновременно мы знаем глагол "пестовать" - то есть заботливо нянчить, бережно взращивать, оберегать и опекать.
Хотелось бы знать, есть ли связь между этими словами, однокоренные ли они. И, если да, то как так получилось? Или же это просто похожие слова, не имеющие ничего общего?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ПЕСТОВАТЬ - питать, воспитывать, о.-с. основа pestъ, в русском языке родственными словами были "пита (с формантом t) и пича"  (пища).

ПЕСТИК (маленький пест) - то, чем толкут, перенос значения по сходству. И.-е. корень pis. Родственными словами являются "пихать и пшено" (сравнить: толокно). Пихать буквально - толкая, толочь, дробить. (Ср. лат pinso - толку. дроблю).